# Binding path for nested arrays in JSONModel

Tags: binding, sapui5

I'm trying to bind a nested array to a tokenizer with SAPUI5. 
The model contains the data like:

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "name": "aabbbcccc",
            "values": {
                "results":[
                    {
                        "ObjVal1": 123, 
                        "ObjVal2": 234
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "effec",
            "values": {
                "results":[
                    {
                        "ObjVal1": 13, 
                        "ObjVal2": 634
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to bind the data contained in **values**, but I have no idea on how to access them in my factory function:

```
tokenizer.bindAggregation("tokens", "/results", function(sId, oContext){
    //here i can access the object in current position
});
```

Since the factory function can only return an object at a time, I can't extract the data from the model and return more than 1 token.

Is there a special binding path format to similar to `/results/*/values/results`?

Comment: You have 2 entries in your root "results" array. Which one you want to bind to the tokenizer?

Comment: the most inner results, the one inside values

Comment: Did you try to use number (index) instead of asterisk?

Comment: yeah, the problem is that I need to bind the data from multiple nested object, I want a tokenizer that contains "123, 234, 13, 634" so I can't fix an index. I don't know if there is a way to do that without asking to backend a dedicated object

Comment: No, there is no such way. The requirement looks really weird. The only thing you can do on UI is to preprocess the backend response (aggregate the data on the UI side ) or ask backend to do that. Personally, I would ask backend..

Comment: well, now that I'm sure about that I will ask to backend! thanks a lot for the help, have a good day!